# After Setting Up Ruby Installer What Command line tools do you use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, command-line

I've installed Ruby on a Windows computer
After Setting Up Ruby Installer What Command line tools do you use?

http://railsinstaller.org/en

I've tried the command 
rvm use 1.9.3

using the command prompt ruby and rails

I get the error message

rvm is not a recognised command

Answer (score 2):

From RVM’s FAQ:

> **Does RVM work on windows? Will it in the future?**
>
> NO. If you would like to manage multiple versions of ruby on windows please use pik which is an excellent tool by Gordon Thiesfeld. You can find it on GitHub. There are plans to include windows support in RVM 2.0.

https://rvm.io/support/faq#does-rvm-work-on-windows-will-it-in-the-future

Answer (score 1):

Doing Rails development on Windows is a little bit more of a challenge and you may run into some annoyances, but it's definitely possible.

[Uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru) worked well for me as a nice alternative to RVM, which doesn't run on Windows. However, if you just want to have one version of Ruby installed on your computer and work with it, you don't even need to bother with Uru.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not the best environment to develop with Ruby ...

RVM doesn't work and PIK hasn't updated for more than 2 years..

[Github of Pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik)

Answer (score 0):

This installer doesn't install RVM. It installs **Ruby interpreter** and **Rails**.

Since you've installed it, I assume you have your Ruby and libraries for it (called `gems`) `rails` and `bundler`. Execute `gem list` in your shell to verify (it should output a looong list).

Then you should create a new Rails project:

```
rails new project_name
```

...and then go into the folder that got created

```
cd project_name
```

bundle what you have:

```
bundle install
```

...and launch the server to see if it works:

```
rails server
```

or

```
rails s
```

You will likely run into issues with `tzinfo` gem if you're on 64-bit Windows, but that can be easily fixed by searching around StackOverflow, it's been discussed.

Gool luck to you. Developing Rails applications in Windows proved to be hard to me. Consider launching **a virtual machine** (using, for example, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) with Linux aboard. That's what you could do **in Linux**:

1. install RVM [as the site suggests](http://rvm.io/):

   ```
   curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
   ```
2. install the latest MRI available - feel free to replace `ruby` with the version you need, like `rvm install 2.0.0`

   ```
   rvm install ruby
   ```
3. select and set as default the Ruby you need, you've tried a similar line apparently with Ruby 1.9.3

   ```
   rvm --default use ruby
   ```
4. another long process

   ```
   gem install rails

   rails new project_name
   ```

   (same as described above)

   ```
   cd project_name
   bundle install
   rails s
   ```

That **should** work, and that's what you've probably seen. Again, I highly recommend using Linux in VirtualBox (or anything similar) for Rails development. A native Linux installation could only be a better environment, but most people are not ready for this just yet.